# Find out how SSL certificate (from letsencrypt) is auto-renewed

Tags: debian, letsencrypt, certbot

I'm running a Debian 8.11 (jessie) server (don't worry, a upgrade is plannend for later this year). It's a LAMP server, with addition to that, an ISPConfig installation. For the website (served through Apache), a SSL certificate is created with letsencrypt (or certbot, not sure if it's different). The thing is that it uses the old `ACMEv1` protocol, which is deprecated and will be removed. Therefore, I'm trying to upgrade my certbot installation to use the new `ACMEv2` protocol.

On the website of certbot it is stated that the `packaged version of certbot` must first be removed. However, this does not seem to be installed through a package manager. (`apt-get remove certbot` results in a `Package "certbot" is not installed, so not removed`).

Now I could manually remove all folders from certbot and letsencrypt, but that doesn't seem like the right way to do things. If I do a `find` for certbot and letsencrypt, I get the following data back:

```
find / -name certbot 2>/dev/null
/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot
/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/certbot
/opt/certbot

find / -name letsencrypt 2>/dev/null
/root/.local/share/letsencrypt
/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/letsencrypt
/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt
/var/log/letsencrypt
/var/lib/letsencrypt
/etc/letsencrypt
```

In addition, I do not know how the certificates are currently being renewed automatically. The system was set up by someone who is no longer available, so I can no longer request that data. I looked in crontab and the like, but I couldn't find anything there. The output of `crontab -e`:

```
0 19 * * * /var/scripts/{{WEBSHOP}}_feed_generator.scr
15 19 * * * /var/scripts/{{WEBSHOP}}_channable_feed_generator.scr

0,15,30,45 * * * * curl --silent https://www.{{WEBSHOP}}/index.php?route=ne/wapcron/do_scheduled

0 7,13,19 * * * /var/backups_www/scripts/createBackup.sh
* * * * * /usr/local/ispconfig/server/server.sh 2>&1 | while read line; do echo `/bin/date` "$line" >> /var/log/ispconfig/cron.log; done
* * * * * /usr/local/ispconfig/server/cron.sh 2>&1 | while read line; do echo `/bin/date` "$line" >> /var/log/ispconfig/cron.log; done
```

So actually I have three questions;

1. How do I find out how the certificates are automatically renewed / how can I stop it so that it does not interfere with the new system
2. How can I properly remove the old system?
3. If the above parts are done, can I follow the installation instructions for certbot-auto? Or are more steps required?

Comment: did you check crontabs?

Comment: @A.B, yes I did. I've added the output of `crontab -e` for clarification.

Comment: are you supposed to mess with that yourself when its probably ispconfig doing it for you? opinion, but: you have a mystery box, one that badly needs an update anyway. it seems to be a lost cause. if letsencrypt still works now you're good for another 3 months at minimum, plenty of times to make plans and migrate to a clean new uptodate box where you know exactly how it is set up.

Comment: this may or may not be your setup https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-debian-8-4-jessie-apache-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-1/2/#-install-lets-encrypt

Comment: @frostschutz, You are correct about your opinion. I do want to migrate to a new setup, but due to timing constraints I don't know if it will be on time. Nevertheless, your link did clear some things up. I ran the `/opt/certbot/./certbot-auto` command, in which certbot updated itself from version 0.12.0 to 1.2.0 and created new certificates. So I believe that concludes the whole upgrade to use ACMEv2. If you could put something like that in an answer, I can mark this question as answered. Thanks for your pointer.